# Information propagation through child object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, software-design

I'm fairly new to unity and was wondering: What is the correct method to propagate information through child objects. For example if I'm making a RPG and I want to create a window that will display all the information of a given character with 2 child object: A skin display of the character, and a stat display of the character. All my object need a reference to the character object to work. We end up with something like that:

- CharacterWindow
- SkinDisplay
- StatDisplay

How I see thing (I can be wrong) is that `CharacterWindow` holds the source of truth and should propagate the information through its child when the reference is updated, but what is the good practice to do that ?

PS: I know that I could make for each child a reference to the parent object and fetch the data from it but idk it seems tedious to me to reference my parent in all my children

Thank for your time and have a good day !

Comment: Id say your character needs to hold the data,  the UI should be fed it to display, just in case you went MMO and inspected other characters

Comment: I understand but my question what related on how my big UI window should fed the info to it sub UI elements

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, you have GameObjects and MonoBehaviors. GameObjects are physical objects in your scene and in the Hierarchy window. You can have one or more MonoBehaviors (written in C#) attached to each GameObject. Now I'll assume you have 3 gameobjects and a corresponding monobehavior attached to each one, which would look like this in the Hierarchy window:

(parent) gameobject - has CharacterWindow monobehavior

- (child) gameobject - has SkinDisplay monobehavior
- (child) gameobject - has StatDisplay monobehavior

Now you can access the parent's gameobject anytime using `this.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject` but I think you'd actually want the CharacterWindow from the parent gameobject instead. You can get it by calling `GetComponentInParent` (here's the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInParent.html)):

```
public class SkinDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    // this will come from the parent gameobject
    private CharacterWindow characterWindow;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterWindow = GetComponentInParent<CharacterWindow>();
    }
}
```

Note you can also call `GetComponentInChildren` to get monobehaviors from children. And there are plural versions of these methods to get all matching monobehaviors in parents or children.

Comment: Hey ! 
Thank for your answer and your time it helped me to understand a bit more how it works.